# Programatically create a Google Sheet and get it's JSON URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Apps Script that will copy a spreadsheet from one team drive to another team drive and then publish the new spreadsheet. I want to get the published URL of a specific sheet or get the JSON URL for the sheet.

This is the working code I have so far:

```
var dFolderID = "destination folder ID";
var sFileID = "source spreadsheet ID";

// get the destination folder
var dFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(dFolderID);

// get the source file
var sFile = DriveApp.getFileById(sFileID);

// name of the new file
var nFileName = "test - " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyyMMddHHmmss");

// make a copy of the spreadsheet
var nFile = sFile.makeCopy(nFileName, dFolder);

// get the ID of the new spreadsheet
var nFileID = nFile.getId();

// publish it
var publishResponse = Drive.Revisions.update({
    published: true,
    publishedOutsideDomain: false,
    publishAuto: true
}, nFileID, 1);
```

At this point, the new spreadsheet has been created, I know the spreadsheets' ID/key, and it is published.

From what I can tell, there is no way to get the published URL because `publishResponse.publishedLink` was depreciated.

So then I thought I could use this URL to get the JSON of a sheet:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/SPREADSHEET_ID/WORKSHEET_ID/public/values?alt=json
```

But for this to work I have to know the `WORKSHEET_ID`. I know I can use the sheet index like 1, 2, 3, etc... but that will break if the sheet order changes.

From what I can tell the only way to get the `WORKSHEET_ID` is by checking this URL:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/SPREADSHEET_ID/private/full
```

If I load this URL in my browser I get an XML response and can see the `WORKSHEET_ID` in it. However, if I try to load this URL from my Google Apps Script it does not work. It looks like it redirects to Google's login page.

```
var privateFullUrl = Utilities.formatString("http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/%s/public/full", nFileID);

var privateFullData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(privateFullUrl, {
    contentType : 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'
});

Logger.log(privateFullData.getContentText());
```

I also checked `SpreadsheetApp.openById(nFileID).getSheetByName("..").getSheetId()` and `SpreadsheetApp.openById(nFileID).getSheetByName("..").getRange(1,1).getDataSourceUrl()` but both of those return a numerical sheet ID instead of the alpha-numeric one that I need for `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/SPREADSHEET_ID/WORKSHEET_ID/public/values?alt=json`.

Is there anyway to either get the published URL or the JSON URL for a specific sheet?

**Edit**

I forgot to mention this is Enterprise G-Suite and sharing outside the company domain is blocked.

Comment: Have you tried [tag:google-query-language]? It provides a endpoint ``/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json`` for getting json. Also, try sending authorization headers in urlfetchapp to your end point `/private/full`. The bearer token can be obtained by `ScriptApp.getAccessToken()`.

Comment: I think that @TheMaster 's comment is correct. If the Spreadsheet is published to Web, you can retrieve the JSON data by ``var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/gviz/tq?gid=0&tqx=out:json");``. ``gid=0`` is the sheet ID. ```###`` is the file ID. If the Spreadsheet is not published, please use the access token.

Comment: Thanks @TheMaster. If you put `ScriptApp.getAccessToken()` as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access private urls, you'd need `oauth` authorization. You can send the authorization header with the bearer token provided by [`ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getOAuthToken()) to bypass full oauth flow.

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}})
```

To get JSON from sheet, You can also use [Google visualization api](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/implementing_data_source#request-format):

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[SPREADSHEET_ID]/gviz/tq?gid=0&tqx=out:json", 
{headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});
```

or

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[SPREADSHEET_ID]/gviz/tq?gid=0&tqx=out:json&access_token="+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain how this changes with the public/private, but you can open any google document, including spreadsheets with the ID like this:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=XXXXX
```

Does that do what you need?

Comment: This is to open the sheet in Chrome. I'm looking for JSON URL and for that I need the publish URL. But @TheMaster's comment helped me. Thanks!